# Creation of PDF file using itextSharp

Tags: asp.net, itext

Hi
 I am creating an ASP.net website where some articles can be uploaded. I need that my users can get PDF version of it by clicking on a button. For this functionality I am using itextSharp.
    I am considering the following two options.
1. I will create the PDF file once(on first request) and reuse it always by checking for the existence of it. 
2. I will create it on the fly and delete it as soon as the PDF file is delivered to the client.
The first approach will lead to faster PDF delivery where as the second approach will lead to saving space. Can anyone please tell me which of the options is better?

I am also wondering if this can be possible without saving the PDF on the server in the first place. So can anyone reply me as soon as possible.

Thanks
Dipa

Comment: This depends on your requirements - is it likely to change over the lifetime of the application?  If you answer is no, then why use itextsharp at all?

Comment: Creating simple PDFs becomes easy once you grasp iTextSharp. But ... creating useful, practical, nice looking PDFs is hard. And hard work. In some ways it makes HTML, CSS, ASP.NET, Javascript and C# look easy! If you've ever struggled with Postscript and SVG you will appreciate why PDFs are so darned hard to master. That is perhaps Adobe's secret of success! 
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/graphics/iTextSharpTutorial.aspx

Comment: i agree with @dev mastering pdf creation is hard work! unless you think space is an issue then i would probably go with option 1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So your tradeoff is saving CPU cycles by storing the file versus saving disk space by always generating it.  I would recommend saving CPU cycles because adding disk storage is cheap and easy (can be done without taking the server offline).  Adding CPUs is relatively more expensive and usually requires taking the server offline (depends on your environment).

**Option 1: Create the PDF on first request**

Advantages:

- PDF is not created unless someone downloads it, so no wasted CPU on creating PDFs nobody wants.
- PDF is a file, so IIS can transmit it to the client as a file, it is available for IIS  caching strategies, etc.

Disadvantages:

- PDF file takes up space on disk.
- Need to mark the PDF (or delete it) if the content is changed, otherwise the PDF version could be out of sync with the article.

**Option 2: Create the PDF on every request**

Advantages:

- PDF is always up-to-date with the latest version of the article.
- Disk space is minimized.

Disadvantages:

- Heavy CPU load on the server if many users request a PDF download.
- Unable to use IIS or other web server caching strategies.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But can you please explain it in details.

Answer (score 2):

You can definitely create the PDF on the fly without writing it to disk. Instead of using a FileStream use a MemoryString:

```
        'PDF Document'
        Dim document As New Document(PageSize.LETTER)
        'Use a memory string so we don't need to write to disk
        Using outputStream As New MemoryStream()
            'Associate the PDF with the stream
            Dim w = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, outputStream)

            'Open the PDF for writing'
            document.Open()

            'Do PDF stuff Here'


            'Close the PDF'
            document.Close()
            'Clear the response buffer'
            Response.Clear()
            'Set the output type as a PDF'
            Response.ContentType = "application/pdf"
            'Disable caching'
            Response.AddHeader("Expires", "0")
            Response.AddHeader("Cache-Control", "")
            'Set the filename'
            Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" & OutputFileName)
            'Set the length of the file so the browser can display an accurate progress bar'
            Response.AddHeader("Content-length", outputStream.GetBuffer().Length.ToString())
            'Write the contents of the memory stream'
            Response.OutputStream.Write(outputStream.GetBuffer(), 0, outputStream.GetBuffer().Length)
            'Close the response stream'
            Response.End()

        End Using
```

iTextSharp is very, very fast for me. I'm on a shared host and I can generate fairly complex PDFs of dozens of pages without noticing any sluggishness.

**EDIT**
Here's the code converted using the [VB.Net to C#](http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/vb-to-csharp/) converter. I haven't tested it and you might have to clean up a couple of things but it should be pretty straight forward.

```
Document document = new Document(PageSize.LETTER);
//Use a memory string so we don't need to write to disk
using (MemoryStream outputStream = new MemoryStream()) {
    //Associate the PDF with the stream
    dynamic w = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, outputStream);

    //Open the PDF for writing'
    document.Open();

    //Do PDF stuff Here'


    //Close the PDF'
    document.Close();
    //Clear the response buffer'
    Response.Clear();
    //Set the output type as a PDF'
    Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
    //Disable caching'
    Response.AddHeader("Expires", "0");
    Response.AddHeader("Cache-Control", "");
    //Set the filename'
    Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + OutputFileName);
    //Set the length of the file so the browser can display an accurate progress bar'
    Response.AddHeader("Content-length", outputStream.GetBuffer().Length.ToString());
    //Write the contents of the memory stream'
    Response.OutputStream.Write(outputStream.GetBuffer(), 0, outputStream.GetBuffer().Length);
    //Close the response stream'
    Response.End();

}
```

To open a PDF in a new window have your link button point to a page such as "CreatePDF.aspx". That page should have this code in it.

Comment: Thanks:) But can you please answer me in C#. and do you know how to open that PDF in a new window after creation(I am using linkbutton). Actually I was trying with target="_blank" but this is not working.

Answer (score 0):

Hi Dipa
As DarrellNoton said it's important to save CPU cycles, i am also agreeing to that. No one will wait for a long time to get the PDF ready, the end user will want it faster.

I will suggest you to create it once and store it in DB as binary format. So that you can access it quickly and it will take less time than creating a new PDF everytime.
Or you can give a name to the PDf file and store the name only in DB. the name can be a guid.

Hope this will help you. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using iTextSharp it can't be possible to create it on the fly. So the second option seems to be good. If you want to reduce the server space used you can run some windows service which will delete all /  the less used PDFs from the server.

It can solve both of your problem i think.

Answer (score 0):

Actually its totally depends on application requirement.Like in my application I don't need to save pdf file on server so after pdf file delivered to client side i delete it from the server.
So in your case if particular user access particular pdf file multiple times then you have to save it on the server,it would save your pdf generation time.