# Itextsharp multiple actions work in Chrome, but not in IE

Tags: vb.net, webforms, itext

I looked at this Stackoverflow question, [iTextSharp multiple actions for pushbuttonfield](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23161573/itextsharp-multiple-actions-for-pushbuttonfield), but I **still** cannot get this working correctly.  This is a proof of concept before we buy the iTextSharp license.

So here is the background.  I am working on a web forms web application written in vb.net.  I open a new browser window to display the PDF in an iframe.  The PDF contains form fields, which the user can fill out.  At the bottom of the form, there will be a submit button to process the form and a save progress button to save their current changes.  After the form is processed/saved, it's supposed to redirect to an HTML page that says "Form Submitted Successfully".  I have this all working in Google Chrome, but it's not doing the redirect to the HTML page in IE.

We will be getting LOTS of PDFs from our customers.  When I create the PDF forms in Acrobat, I add the 2 buttons to the bottom of the PDF.  This ensures the correct placement of the buttons, based on where it fits for that PDF.  So the buttons will always have the same names, "btnSaveProgress" and "btnProcessForm".

In the codebehind for the source of the iframe, I have this iTextSharp code:

```
Using myPdfReader As New PdfReader(strFullFilePathName)
    Context.Response.Clear()
    Context.Response.ContentType = "application/pdf"

    Using stamper As PdfStamper = New PdfStamper(myPdfReader, Response.OutputStream)
       stamper.ViewerPreferences = PdfWriter.HideToolbar
       Dim hostUrl As String = Request.Url.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Authority)
       Dim btnArray() As String = {"btnSaveProgress", "btnProcessForm"}
       Dim intCounter = 0

       For Each btnName As String In btnArray
           Dim saveButtonField As PushbuttonField = stamper.AcroFields.GetNewPushbuttonFromField(btnName)
           Dim pff As PdfFormField = saveButtonField.Field
           Dim myAction As PdfAction = PdfAction.CreateSubmitForm("../../Common/Services/StaticFormSubmissionHandler.ashx?submissionType=" & intCounter & "&formID=" & intFormID & "&resultID=" & intResultID & "&templateName=" & Server.UrlEncode(sShortName), Nothing, PdfAction.SUBMIT_EXCL_F_KEY)
           myAction.Next(New PdfAction(hostUrl & "/Main/Pages/FormSub.htm"))
                    'pff.SetAdditionalActions(PdfName.U, myAction)
           pff.Action = myAction
           stamper.AcroFields.ReplacePushbuttonField(btnName, pff)
           intCounter += 1
       Next
    End Using
End Using
```

The save/process submission works, but the redirect only works in Chrome.  In IE, it makes the iframe blank.  I'm not seeing any errors or anything.  Also, in IE, the PDF has the menu bars displayed.  I understand if this is strictly related to the Reader in the IE browser, and I have no control over it.  But it would be nice if the `stamper.ViewerPreferences = PdfWriter.HideToolbar` would work.

Thank you so much in advance for any advice/input.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12473356/pdf-file-not-showing-up-in-internet-explorer which is a question that matches what you see in MSIE. That is: nothing. You aren't using best practices. As explained in the "iText in Action - 2nd edition" book, it's not a good idea to write PDF bytes straight to the `Response.OutputStream` because some browsers (such as MSIE) require that you set at least the content length in the HTTP header. See also the answer by Chris Haas to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4471376/creation-of-pdf-file-using-itextsharp

Comment: Actually, my comment may be wrong in the sense that the PDF is displayed in MSIE, but the HTML doesn't show up in the iFrame. That doesn't mean that the the multiple actions doesn't work, and it certainly doesn't mean that there's an iTextSharp problem, after all: the file that "works" on Chrome is **identical** to the file that "doesn't work" on MSIE. In that case, the culprit is the browser/PDF viewer combination. It's most definitely not an iTextSharp problem.

Comment: I'm with @BrunoLowagie, the problem is browser/server related and nothing to do with iTextSharp. Also, be careful when saying that `stamper.ViewerPreferences = PdfWriter.HideToolbar` doesn't work because it absolutely does, its just that not every renderer out there interprets the *hint* as you want/expect it to. Also remember that these new-fangled in-browser renderers weren't really even a concept back when the PDF spec was written.